# 2d mixed with activity, is that easy in android?

Tags: android

My whole application is very common except an area that display 2d graphics(text marqueezing and some visual effect). The app is like a media player --- it has buttons, and lots of dialogs(for configuration uses).

I wonder how could I do this?

First I use activity and build-in animations but obviously the animations are too limited.

So should I use game engine to achieve good graphics? But how about those dialogs in this case? Are they hard to implement in game engine? Or I can mix activity dialog with 2d game engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have difficulty to use a 2D engine with dialogs and classic UI.
I advice you to look at [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org). It's a very well known game engine, really easy for 2D.

Comment: Ok, then seems that a 2D engine is enough for me. Now I'll try AppEngine. Thanks!